# Implementing logbase2 function in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
loga_base2 :: (Int b) => Int -> Int 
 loga_base2  b 
         | b == 1    = 0
         | b == 2    = 1
         | otherwise = 1 + loga_base2 (b `div` 2)
```

Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')
Every time I try :r This error appears

Comment: When I run your code, I got another error. Are you sure this error is related to your `loga_base2`.

Comment: There is also an indentation problem in this code.  Line 2 needs to have the same indentation as line 1, because it's part of the same definition.  This is not just a stylistic choice but a requirement by the syntax of the language.

Answer (score 3):

`Int` is not a typeclass, and thus `Int` can not be used in a type constraint. You should implement this as:

```
loga_base2 :: Int -> Int
loga_base2  b 
    | b == 1 = 0
    | b == 2 = 1
    | otherwise = 1 + loga_base2 (b `div` 2)
```

then we retrieve the following sample output:

```
Prelude> loga_base2 10
3
Prelude> loga_base2 37
5
Prelude> loga_base2 73
6
```